# Application Exited when i turn on Bluetooth programatically in a Button click in android

Tags: android

In my application in a button click i want to programatically enable Bluetooth for this i am using below code and i am able to enable the Bluetooth but after pressing Yes in the Bluetooth enable dialog i am exiting application,i don't want to exit the application i want to show the same screen after enabling the Bluetooth also how can i do this please check the below code i am using for enabling Bluetooth and also onActivityResult code method.`enter code here`

```
    if(v.getId() == R.id.Button)
{
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    final ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter = null;
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
    }
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new    Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

}

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
    switch(requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      String name = data.getStringExtra("Bluetooth Enabled");
      Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the book: " + " " + name,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      break;
  }
   }
  }
```

Comment: can any one pls give me reply...

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Add [logging](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to your code.

> ```
> String name = data.getStringExtra("Bluetooth Enabled");
> Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the book: " + " " + name ...
> ```

What do you expect `data` to be? - It is the result data of the Activity Android launches to ask for permission to turn on Bluetooth. What information are you trying to extract from it?

It seems to me there is some important code missing in your snippet, namely in `onActivityResult`.

Please give more detail and provide logcat output.

Comment: Dear Hanno i want to show one Dialog and also call one function after enabling the bluetooth can u tell me how to do it i alreay mentioned onActivityResult code also in the above thread